# gengetopt: Multiple arguments split with space, not comma

Tags: c, parsing

When specifying an option as

```
option "foo" f "" string optional multiple(1-)
```

gengetopt correctly builds up the array `foo_args` when called as:

```
./a.out -f A -f B -f C        # {"A", "B", "C"}
./a.out -f A,B,C              # {"A", "B", "C"}
```

But this only grabs the first "A", and considers "B" and "C" to be unnamed

```
./a.out -f A B C              # {"A"}
```

I'm not using `--unnamed-opts`, because I don't have any unnamed arguments. I'd like to support that style, because it seems more common… is that <del>easily</del> possible?

Comment: Who defines what's common? To me the comma separated list looks more "common" ...

Comment: Unix file names may contain commas, people are used to giving each file name as one token, it's how shell globbing works, etc… (i.e. `./a.out -f *.x` gives `./a.out -f A.x B.x` not a comma-separated list)

Answer (score 0):

You might try puting quotes around the space separated list items, like so: `-f "A B C"` and do an extra parsing.

Comment: But what if the file names contain spaces? That's why you get a nicely split argv[], so you don't have to worry about things like this, the shell does it for you.